# How to install applications from KDE desktop on CentOS

Tags: kde, centos, kde4

I've just installed CentOS 6.5 in a virtual machine. I know how to install packages with command-line `yum` but I'm wondering how to do the same from the GUI (KDE).

They apparently did not write [documentation for CentOS 6](http://centos.org/docs/). Docs for previous releases only explain how to choose packages during initial installation. And I cannot find nothing remotely similar to "install applications" or "package manager" in the KDE menu. Google only returns results on how to install CentOS itself.

What's the name of the standard graphical package manager and how can I launch it?

Comment: Yes there is no explicit documentation for 6, there is the docs from 4 & 5 along with the official RHEL6 docs. All the RHEL docs are here: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/

Comment: @slm Thank you. I could find a [reference to a GUI tool](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-next-steps.html) but it only mentions its path within Gnome menu (not even the tool name). I'll keep on reading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application binary is called `gpk-application`. It comes in the `gnome-packagekit` package:

```
# yum install gnome-packagekit gnome-packagekit-extra
```

You apparently need to run it as non-privileged user. It does not seem to create menu entries in KDE so:

```
$ gpk-application &
```

*The [forum post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4868) where I got this info claims that it's bundled in the "Graphical Administration Tools" group and KDE creates a menu item under "Applications → Administration → Add/Remove Software". It wasn't the case for me.*

Comment: This forum post has instructions for creating the menu items yourself: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4868#p198501